# Xamarin.Forms WebView doesn't show content on iOs

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm downloading html and then trying to display it by WebView like this:

```
htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.BaseUrl = this.requestUrl;
htmlSource.Html = await WebRequest(formContent);
```

other function

```
guiWebView.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
guiWebView.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
guiWebView.Source = viewSource;
```

It works well on Android, but on iOs I get only frame of unload image. Does anybody have some idea?

Result:
[image]

Comment: Does it have a Height and Width Request? It would be on the WebView itself, at least in Xaml.

Comment: I set width and height request at some values but still doesnt work :/

Comment: Worth a shot anyways, seems to be a common issue. Here’s a little more help https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/52719/xamarin-forms-webview-not-loading-url

Comment: still, nothing... :( thought NSAppTransportSecurity but it didn't